# How do you change background colors of different containers and columns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

Ok, so I'm brand new here (and to programming) and I'm not even sure If the questions I'm going to ask is worded correctly or makes sense, but here it goes.

I am working on a bootstrap theme for a client, I am trying to change the background colors. I do not want the page to be all the same background color. I would like certain rows to have a different background color from the rest of the page. How can I accomplish this? I've tried adding unique  tags to the containers I'm working on with the background color I want, but no matter what I do NOTHING is changing. I know this is something simple and I just need a simple explanation as to how to make this work! HELP!

Comment: put the code/html you've tried in the question, it will get you a faster/better response.

Comment: please, post your code!

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do that.
For the background in the divs:
You can do:

```
<head>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color: red;
    }
    .backg1{
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;}
    .content{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;}
</style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="backg1">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Is only work with the css properties. You need paste the code to try help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add class="bgColor"

Like:

```
<div class="bgColor">
....
</div>
```

Your css:

```
.bgColor{
 background: #dadada;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your styles in custom_style.css, in which you can add CSS properties for elements. Inside your custom_style.css you give background color you want.That's it, Its just the work of CSS. No other process or procedure to .

consider #Page 1

```
    /* Include Bootstrap.css and custom_style.css etc */ 
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="Web_page_home">
         .............
        </div>
      </div>
    /* include JQuery.js and Bootstrap.js */
```

Consider #page 2

```
    /* Include Bootstrap.css and custom_style.css etc */ 
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="Web_page_about">
         .............
        </div>
      </div>
    /* include JQuery.js and Bootstrap.js */
```

Here goes the working of CSS "Custom_style.css" has

```
    #Web_page_home { background-color:red; }
    #Web_page_about{ background-color:green; }
```

The output will b the Page 1 backgorund will b in red and another page 2 will be in green.

if you didn't understand still i will attach fiddle.